# Knockout Validation min/max validation with commas in value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have the following fields in my ViewModel:

```
self.agi = ko.observable("")
        .extend({ required: true, min: .01 });
```

But when I enter a value of 1,000 I get the following error:

> Please enter a value greater than or equal to 0.01.

1000 validates properly. How can I make the validation disregard the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom validation for min/max validation with commas in value.

```
ko.validation.rules['minCheck'] = {
  validator: function(val, min) {
      val=val.replace(/\,/g,'');
      return ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(val) || val >= min;
    },
 message: 'Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.'
};
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyG2Y/2/)